# roslib.packages is deprecated, what's its successor?

Tags: ros, roslib, packages, rospkg, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

The documentation says [roslib.packages is deprecated](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roslib/html/python/roslib.packages-module.html) and lets know that rospkg is the new stable API. However I can't find the equivalent methods in rospkg, what are the new get_pkg_dir(), find_resource() ...?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202822/roslib.packages-is-deprecated,-what%27s-its-successor?/) by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 454 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a snippet that uses `rospkg` instead of `roslib` to get a package path:

```
import rospkg
rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
rospack.get_path('beginner_tutorials')
```

Here's the documentation for the `RosPack` class http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/rospkg_packages.html. I'm unaware of a replacement for `find_resource()`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2015-02-11**:
Thanks for the snippet, it works!
Hope there will be an equivalent, this method is really handy.